# Average of histogram values OpenCV

Tags: opencv, histogram

I am kinda new to Open CV. I am using `CalcHist()` to calculate the Histogram of an image gray scale image. I now want to calculate the average of the histogram values. Can you please tell me how I can achieve this?

Am using c++, compiled by Gcc in ubuntu, opencv 2.4.3.

Comment: C++ or what are you using? Also, please share your code for computing the histogram. That makes it usually easier to write an understandable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CalcHist 5th attribute is the Mat holding the histogram values. Access its .data[].

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that. Sorry for asking again, but can you please tell me What each parameter actually means? I tried seeing from tutorials, but the way they have put it feels slightly complicated for me.

Comment: The fifth attribute actually is an array. Am sorry, but I maybe wrong. Is it actually Mat?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Search for examples like this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html)